# Crowdsale smart contract

Tags: ico, crowdsale

We need a template of a fully workable crowdsale contract
It should be with the time frame and we should specify rate and the wallet where all raised funds will go

Comment: Here you have some contracts used in some ICOs https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts

Comment: And here: https://github.com/adamdossa/OxTokenICO/blob/master/contracts/OxToken.sol